# is dimension of an abstract tree structure equal to its depth

Tags: data-structures, tree

The question is based on the premise that the dimension of a list can be determined(i.e. we accepted that a list of list is 2D and a list of list of list is 3D etc.)

According to the [informal definition on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension), the dimension of a mathematical space (or object)[Here is data structure] is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point within it.

So the dimension of a list depends on how many layers of sublist it contains.
What about an abstract tree? I believe the term `depth` is used for an abstract tree, which is similar to the idea of 'dimension of list'.

So is dimension of an abstract tree equal to the depth of an abstract tree. Or I am just asking a wrong question like how fast can a fish climb a tree?

[Edit: By tree above, I mean a rooted tree.)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous -- there are different notions of dimension and different ways you can topologize trees. You need to specify what definitions you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of interpreting your question. Under what is perhaps the most natural one (that of the [dimension of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(graph_theory))), trees are typically 2 dimensional (although in degenerate cases can be 1-dimensional or even 0-dimensional). This is because trees can be defined as being connected acyclic graphs, and it is easy to prove that all such graphs can be drawn in Euclidean 2-space with non-crossing edges of unit length. There *are* other definitions of dimension (such as the [metric dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_dimension_(graph_theory)) of a graph) in which trees can have variable dimension, though in that case it doesn't correspond directly to the depth.

Your informal definition runs into problems since once you specify a traversal-order for a tree then you can specify any node by giving its position in the traversal-order. Does that make it one-dimensional? The ability to define iterators over data-structures presents a problem for any robust definition of dimension of a data structure in much the same way that [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) presented a problem for mathematicians who were trying to formalize the notion of dimension.

Comment: I just skimmed through the dimension of a graph and the definition stated on that page.
Lets see if I understand that correctly, trees are typically 2 dimensional because, by construction, every edge is of unit length and all of the nodes can be represented on a 2 dimensional space.

If I define that a repesentation of a node in a tree must start with a root node, going through layer by layer, would you agree that the dimension of the tree is same as the depth of the tree?

Comment: @Joey It doesn't matter if you specify a root node -- if you model a tree as a graph then its graph dimension is 2 (or less). You would need adopt a different definition of dimension. For example -- perhaps you can try to define the dimension of a data structure as the least `d` such that the complexity of summing the entries (assuming that they are numbers) is in some sense `O(n^d)` (where something exponential would be infinite dimensional). This is just a suggestion -- it isn't clear how you could get a crisp definition out of it.

Answer (score 0):

And there are different types of trees.

Your concept is valid only for simple binary trees.